# Why C doesn't have a function which is used like strcpy() and check buffer size automatically to prevent buffer overflow bug?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I'm really wondering why there's no function in C like `strcpy()`, `memcpy()`, etc. that automatically checks the size of the buffer. Something that behaves like this:

```
#define strcpy2(X, Y) strncpy(X, Y, sizeof(X))
```

Some people tell me: "Because it's old language." But, C is not a dead language. IOS can fix the standard, and new functions like `strncpy` have been added.

Others tell me: "It causes performance issues." But, I argue "if a function like that existed, you can still use the old function in situations where performance is important. In all situation, you can use that function and you can expect security improvement."

Still others tell me: "So, there's a function like `strncpy()`", or "C is designed for professional developer who consider this problem", but `strncpy()` does not do the check automatically - developers must determine the size of the buffer, and still large programs like Chrome, which are made by professional developers, have buffer overflow vulnerabilities.

I want to know a technical reason why such a function cannot be made.

---

*English is not my native language. so I guess there are some mistakes... sorry about this. (Edit (cmaster): Should be fixed now. Hope you like the new wording.)

Comment: Why do you think "IOS" is responsible for `strncpy` or for anything in the standard. I think that function has been around long before Apple even started using "i" in any product names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To really understand the reason why C functions cannot do what you want, you need to understand about the difference between arrays and pointers, and what it means that an array decays to a pointer. Just to give you an idea what I'm talking about:

```
int array[7];    //define an array
int* pointer = array;    //define a pointer that points to the same memory, array decays into a pointer to the first int

//Now the following two expressions are precisely equivalent, since array decays to a pointer again:
pointer[3];
array[3];

//However, the sizeof of the two is not the same:
assert(sizeof(array) == 7*sizeof(int));    //this is what you used in your define
assert(*pointer == sizeof(int));    //probably not what you expected

//Now the thing gets nasty: Array declarations in function arguments truly decay into pointers!
void foo(int bar[9]) {
    assert(sizeof(bar) == sizeof(int));    //I bet, you didn't expect this!
}

//This is, because the definition of foo() is truly equivalent to this definition:
void foo(int* bar) {
    assert(sizeof(bar) == sizeof(int));
}

//Transfering this to your #define, this will definitely not do what you want:
void baz(char aBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE], const char* source) {
    strcpy2(aBuffer, source);    //This will copy only the first four or eight bytes (depending on the size of a pointer on your system), no matter how big you make BUFFER_SIZE!
}
```

I hope, I enticed you to google for array-pointer-decay now...

The truth is, that the C language relies heavily on the fact that no array size is required to correctly access an array element, only the surrounding loops need to know the size. As such, arrays decay to pure pointers in many places, and once they are decayed, there is no bringing back the size of the array. This brings a great deal of flexibility and simplicity to the language (very easy handling of subarrays!), but it also makes a function that behaves like your `#define` impossible.

Answer (score 5):

If X is a pointer, and it usually is, then sizeof X tells you nothing about the size of the array to which X points.  The size must be passed as a parameter.

Comment: It's just a example to explain my question... Is it hard to make that functions when design a compiler?

Comment: @user3314069 It's not in the standard that *any* function can get the size of an array passed implicitly. It's a very fundamental feature of the language that arrays decay to pointers. To have such a function, you would need to introduce a new *keyword* `strcpy` into the language for a very special usage, which would fail in the general case. If you want such on-the-fly fixes, use C++ - the feature you propose does not fit a clean, minimalistic language like C. If you want safe string handling in C, take a look at the POSIX-2008 functions `strdup`, `asprintf`, etc.

Comment: You can create a string type that knows its size; it's just a struct with a size variable and a bufptr. Then write a function that takes such structs as its argument. However, standard C strings are do not and can not know their size.

Answer (score 2):

Technical reason is: in C the buffer size cannot be checked automatically, because it is not managed by the language. Functions like `strcpy` operate on pointers, and though pointers point to buffers, there is no way for `strcpy` implementation to know how long a buffer is. Your suggestion of using `sizeof` does not work, since `sizeof` returns the object size, not the size of the buffer a pointer points to. (In your example it would return always the same number, most probably 4 or 8).

C language makes programmer responsible for managing buffer sizes, so one can use functions like `strncpy` and pass the buffer size explicitly. But it will never be possible to implement safe version of `strcpy` in C, since it would require fundamental changes in the way the language treats pointers.

All of it applies to C descendants like C++ of Objective C too.

Comment: @cmaster: It won't if `Y` is longer then thr size provided by `X`, as `X` wouldn't be 0-terminated.

Comment: It's not at all impossible, probably all compilers store the length in some way or another. How do you think a `free` or `delete[]` would work on an array otherwise? I'm not saying the idea is wrong, just that "there's no way for... to know..." is a stretch.

Comment: You assume that the buffer length is the length of the allocated memory. This is not the case always. I can malloc a memory area of length 1000 and then treat it as 10 buffers each of length 100. How can the compiler know that my buffers are of length 100 not 1000 then? And such solution - manual memory management - is done very often in C programs.  So it is really impossible - if it is introduced in some way, the changes to the core language would be so big that it shouldn't be called C anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char* x;

if (!asprintf(&x, "%s", y)) {
    perror("asprintf");
    exit(1);
}

// from here, x will contain the content of y
```

---

Under the assumption, that y is Null terminated, this works safely.

(Written a on tablet, so forgive any silly errors, please.)